# Displaying a specific data in html ionic

Tags: ionic4

I'm trying to display a specific username using the user uid in firebase, but i can't display it in the html. I try to get the username from the userColl by the Uid. For the html, i tried using *ngFor, but there's problem indicating that it can only be used for array

Here's is the code:

```
read_Username() {
    return this.firestore.collection('userColl',ref => ref
    .where('userUid', '==', this.userUid)).snapshotChanges();
    //return this.firestore.collection('/userColl/userUid' + this.userUid).snapshotChanges();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     //this.userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
     this.read_Username().subscribe(data => {

      this.user = data.map(e => {
        if(this.user != null){
           return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          userUid: e.payload.doc.data()['userUid'],
          username: e.payload.doc.data()['username'],
        };
        }

      })
      console.log(this.user);

    });

    }
```

The html:

```
 <ion-card class="welcome-card">
<img src="/assets/shapes.svg" alt=""/>
<div>
<ion-card-header >
  <ion-card-subtitle></ion-card-subtitle>
  <ion-card-title> {{userUid}}</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <p>{{username?.username}}</p>
</ion-card-content>
```

Comment: You're saying that your {{userUid}} is not displaying properly right? Is that what you mean?

Comment: actually is both the userUid and the username

Comment: You might need to initialize your userUid and username into a variable (As I put in the answer below - userUid:string and username:string). Then set those variables using 'this.'. Then it should be able to display on your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your codes to this:

```
read_Username() {
    return this.firestore.collection('userColl',ref => ref
    .where('userUid', '==', this.userUid)).snapshotChanges();
    //return this.firestore.collection('/userColl/userUid' + this.userUid).snapshotChanges();
  }

  userUid:string;
  username:string;
  ngOnInit() {
     this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     //this.userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
     this.read_Username().subscribe(data => {

      this.user = data.map(e => {
        if(this.user != null){
           return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          userUid: e.payload.doc.data().userUid,
          username: e.payload.doc.data().username,
        };
        }

      })
      console.log(this.user);

    });

    }
```

The html:

```
 <ion-card class="welcome-card">
<img src="/assets/shapes.svg" alt=""/>
<div>
<ion-card-header >
  <ion-card-subtitle></ion-card-subtitle>
  <ion-card-title>{{userUid}}</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <p>{{username}}</p>
</ion-card-content>
```

If it doesn't work, change the

```
userUid: e.payload.doc.data().userUid,
username: e.payload.doc.data().username,
```

to:

```
userUid: e.payload.doc.data()['userUid'],
username: e.payload.doc.data()['username'],
```